# Office365/Outlook Mail REST API Track failed email send

Tags: php, outlook

How can I track failed/bounced emails thru API?

I've got this in my mailbox after send to invalid email:

```
This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

Delivery to the following recipients failed.

   asdsd@bvcbwe.df
```